# Angular Autocomplete Implementation Generates CORS Error

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material, .net-core-angular

I am trying out the auto complete feature in angular and I keep running into CORS error.
Other API calls work fine.

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52008243/angular-cors-issue-querying-an-endpoint-every-5-seconds) but it wasnt very useful.

Below is my implementation

```
ngOnInit(): void {
     const url = this.setupApiUrl + "GetBranches/";
    this._dataService.SetHeaders()
   this.branchNameCtrl.valueChanges
     .pipe(
       debounceTime(2000),        
       tap(() => {
         this._dataService.SetHeaders();
         this.errorMsg = "";
         this.branchList = [];
         this.isLoading = true;
       }),
       switchMap(value => this._dataService.GetResults<BranchViewModel>(url + value)
         .pipe(
           finalize(() => {
             this.isLoading = false
           }),
         )
       )
     )
     .subscribe(data => {
       if (data.result['Search'] === undefined) {
         this.errorMsg = data.result['Error'];
         this.branchList = [];
       } else {
         this.errorMsg = "";
         this.branchList = data.result['Search'];
        }        console.log(this.branchList);
     });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the call `this._dataService.SetHeaders()` is using headers not allowed by your the server's CORS policy. If you are using dotnet core, you may need to call AllowAnyHeader or AllowCredentials, or may be allow a specific header.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-the-allowed-request-headers

Comment: Yeah,  but I do have other API calls using the same headers working fine

Comment: ```if (adminApiConfiguration.CorsAllowAnyOrigin)
                        {
                            builder.AllowAnyOrigin();
                        }``` "CorsAllowAnyOrigin": true,

Comment: ```public SetHeaders(page?: number, itemsPerPage?: number) {

    const tokenValue = "Bearer " + this._securityService.getToken();   
      this.headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': tokenValue,
        'Pagination': page + "," + itemsPerPage
      });
    }```